# What does implicit conversion from double to int64_t in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, implicit-conversion

Could someone shed a light on the way this code behaves:

```
double x = 9223371036854;
int64_t y1 = /* trunc */ (x * 1000000);
int64_t y2 = round(x * 1000000);
cout << y1 << " <= " << y2 << endl;
assert( y1 <= y2 ); // fail
```

This code fails due to `y1` actually equals to `9223371036854000000` while `y2` is `9223371036853999616`.
After uncommenting `trunc` everything is ok (assertion verified).

Compiled by gcc-4.6.3-1ubuntu5 with `g++ --std=c++0x x.cpp`.

Why `int64_t(round(x * 1000000))` is less than `int64_t(x * 1000000)` where `x` is `double`?

And why results of `int64_t(trunc(x * 1000000))` is different from `int64_t(x * 1000000)`?

Comment: Erm, so what's the question?

Comment: Are you asking why you get the same result with or without `trunc` (which is what I see, with that code and that compiler)? That's because the argument to `trunc` is already an integer, so the function does nothing. Or do you get different results? In that case, please let us know what you see and what you expected (and why).

Comment: Why this code fails. Uncommenting `trunc` makes it work.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, argument of `trunc` is `double`. Verified with `template<typename T> void foo(T x); void foo(double x) {};` and later `foo(x * 1000000)`.

Comment: I thought that presence of `assert` and saying that it works with `trunc` is pretty clear. But looks like many people didn't got it right.

Comment: There is no `round` method in standard cmath, can you show us the code for round?

Comment: @bkausbk, It is there since [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) and I guess you can use `math.h` variant in a same way. Moreover I suspect that any function may bring you the same result (especially manually written).

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found why it works like this (`y1 == 92233710368540000000` and assert fails).

GCC optimized out run-time calculation of `y1` without loosing precision which clearly happens in `y2`. 
More intersting is that expression of literals have no such property

```
double x = 9223371036854;
int64_t y1 = /* trunc */ (x * 1000000);
int64_t y2 = round(x * 1000000);
cout << y1 << " <= " << y2 << endl;
assert( int64_t(9223371036854.0 * 1000000) <= int64_t(round(9223371036854e6)) ); // ok
assert( int64_t(x * 1000000) <= int64_t(round(x * 1000000)) ); // fails
assert( y1 <= y2 ); // fails
```

And if I'll move out `1e6` outside of expressions everything works as expected:

```
double x = 9223371036854.0 * 1000000;
int64_t y1 = /* trunc */ (x);
int64_t y2 = round(x);
cout << y1 << " <= " << y2 << endl;
assert( int64_t(x) <= int64_t(round(x)) ); // ok
assert( y1 <= y2 ); // ok
```

But probably my assumption about optimization is incorrect.

Comment: Just to make clear. This is only my assumption. Maybe someone knows exactly why that code behaves like this.

Comment: Please can you edit your original post or is your question answered now?

Comment: @bkausbk, this is candidate for answer